# get C++ `this` in C#

Tags: c#, pointers, this

I need to have a pointer to the instance of a structure inside that structure. Is the following code a correct way to get such pointer:

```
struct A
{
    int a;
    unsafe public A* p;
    unsafe public A(int x)
    {
        a = x;
        fixed(A* q = &this)
        {
            p = q;
        }
    }
}
```

Here `p` contains the pointer I need and it works. But is it a correct way to get the pointer. Can the the address of the object change unexpectedly by GC, while `p` pointer to previous location?

Comment: `fixed` exists for a reason. It [fixes the pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/153390/11683). After you exit the `fixed` block, it does not.

Comment: If the `A` struct is stored inside a field of a class or in an array, then the GC may move the containing reference type and thus the struct.